# Computing Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am using the `[h,p,ksstat,cv] = kstest(x,'cdf',y);` function in Matlab to  find the `ksstat` and p-value. My `x` is `x(1,1:10) = [0.16;1.21;4.41;0.09;0.64;0.36;0.04;6.76;0.04;0.49]`and my `y = chi2cdf(x,9);` which is the `cdf` I am specifying or testing. Although I get this error:

```
Error using kstest (line 160)
Hypothesized CDF matrix must have 2 columns.
```

Normally I would have `[h,p,ksstat,cv] = kstest(x,'cdf',y);` where 
`y = makedist('ChiSquared');` but as you may know the distribution Chi-squared does not exist so I am not sure how to get around this issue. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write:

```
[h,p,ksstat,cv] = kstest(x,'cdf',[x y]);
```

as the [documentation says](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest.html#input_argument_namevalue_CDF):

> When CDF is a matrix, column 1 contains a set of possible x values, and column 2 contains the corresponding hypothesized cumulative distribution function values G(x).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, would you know how to specify a cdf where we simply have F(x) = x^4 in MATLAB?